# Verifying Gauss's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let

$B:=\{(x,y): |x| \leq 3, |y| \leq 3, x^2+y^2 \geq 1\}$ and the vector field $v(x,y)={(x-y,x)}^{T}$

I need to draw B and the boundary $\partial B$.
I drew the region. It would be the red lined part.  Would only be the outer square the boundary or the inner circle as well?

and then I need to verify Gauss's theorem.
I have calculated div $v(x,y)=1$. However I do not know how to set up the two integrals for checking their equality.
I think I need the parameterization $(x,y)=(r\cdot cos (\phi), r \cdot sin (\phi))$ here?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your picture is wrong. The outside boundary should be a square!

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you professor! I have edited it, could you please maybe help me with the integrals?

Comment: The area integral needs no integration. Just look at it. For the line integrals, parametrize  the circle and the four edges of the square. Remember that you're doing flux, not work.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you professor, I parameterized the circle and the square, calculated the tangent vectors and got the first integral. However for the second integral, the area integral, would it just be Area of Square minus Area of circle? But how could I do it with an integral? $\int_{B} div v d(x,y)$, even if apparantly not needed I would like to know how I could  proceed there,  div v = 1 so, $\int_{B} 1 d(x,y)$, what would the limits be here?

Comment: Use polar coordinates in four pieces (but take advantage of symmetry whenever you can).